# getting my data back after accidentally unallocated space

Tags: hard-drive

I have a windows 8.1 laptop, it asked me to create a system recovery disk to return the laptop to its factory default when needed, i inserted my usb hard disk, unfortunately it had my most important data on it, when the wizard tried to create the system recovery, something went wrong immediately and the hard disk became 31 GBs after 688 GBs. I went to disk management and found that the rest of the space became unallocated space, and noooo data in the hard drive.
Please help me it's very important how to get my data back???

Comment: this question was answered a lot of times with many diferent flavors. i suggest you to http://superuser.com/search before post a repeated question.

Comment: The chances you'll get all your data back are very slim since you reformatted the whole HDD and actually wrote new data on it. It is possible however that data recovery software will recover a part of your data is you did only a quick format.

Answer (score 0):

The chances of you getting all your data back is close to nill.  You may want to try run photorec (or recuva or equivalent) to see what can be picked up by bypassing the file system.  Chances are good you will be able to recover some stuff, but it will be a long, manual process - and you almost certainly won't get everything.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, i am actually using recuva now but it takes a very very long time as you said, thanks again, wish me luck